# How to get the Polygon mode with OpenTK?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm setting the Polygon Mode like this in order to draw the wireframe:

```
GL.PolygonMode(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, PolygonMode.Line);
GL.PolygonMode(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, PolygonMode.Point);
GL.PolygonMode(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, PolygonMode.Fill);
```

I believe that there is a GL function that returns the Polygon mode, like this:

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_POLYGON_MODE, &polygonMode);
```

Does OpenTK offer something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the PolygonMode by using the `GL.GetInteger` function, as shown below:

```
    PolygonMode pm = (PolygonMode) GL.GetInteger(GetPName.PolygonMode);
    if (pm == PolygonMode.Line)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LINE");
    }
```

I didn't find it at first because I was trying to use `GetIndexedPName` instead of `GetPName`, so be careful in case you are not finding the `PolygonMode` constant.

Thanks anyway for your help